# Retain the original order after sorting with tablesorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, tablesorter

All my table data comes in a sorted order. I am using table sorter to sort on a column by date. It is working fine. Now I want to provide a option to revert the sort to original sorted order which i received.

How can i do that

1) one way i am thinking is cloning the table before sending it to table sorter. Is there any better approach than that

Thanks

Comment: Well, how was it sorted originally? Is there a reason you can't trigger a sort on that field?

Comment: . The sorted order comes from server. There is no proper logic for that order. It is ordered based on user preference. One thing i can do is go back to server again to get the table which I dont think is a good solution.

Comment: If it comes from the server completely unsorted, then I would just sort it automatically on arrival and leave it that way. I can't think of any reason why you'd want to return it to the original, quasi-random order.

Comment: Well, the order doesnt make sense logically. but it is the order most of users want to see. Now, i am adding this feature of seeing by date order. so when i do that my previous order is lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a fork of tablesorter on github in which I added a new option named `sortReset` which after clicking on the header a third time will reset the table to it's original order. Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sortreset-sortrestart.html)

Answer (score 0):

I added a new column to original table which is numbering to rows. So now if i sort by date and want the previous order, i simply sort by the newly created column.